# Find a value of an input field in a table just above the active row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery, i would like to find a value in an input field just above the current table row, for example if tr id="two" is active, i can find the value of input id="x" at tr id="one" and if tr id="three" is active, i can find the value of input id="y" at tr id="two", Suggestions!

```
<table>
<tr id="one">
<input type="text" id="x"/>
</tr>
<tr id="two">
<input type="text" id="y"/>
</tr>
<tr id="three">
<input type="text" id="z"/>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by active row? You need the value when you click or when you enter the mouse?? What is your condition for active!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$('tr.active').prev().find('input').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

//first part can depend upon how/when you want to find it.

```
$('tr.active').prev().find('input[type="text"]').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid jQuery..

```
var x = document.querySelector("tr.active");
var value = x.parentNode.firstChild.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr.active').prev().children()[0].val()
```